# Prevent from changing the speed on collision and separation

Tags: javascript, collision-detection

I was making a agar.io like game. i have a separate function which separates the blobs or circle from overlapping. it does prevent them from overlapping but changes the speed of the blobs. i dont want any change in the rate of movement. bigger or more massive blobs have slower speed than the smaller ones. but my separate function cause the bigger blobs to move with smaller blobs. here's the code i use for separating the blobs.

```
function separatePlayer() {
    blobsPlayer.forEach(function(a, i) {
        blobsPlayer.forEach(function(b, j) {
            if (i == j)
                return;
            var ref1 = a;
            var ref2 = b;
            /*if(a.mass > b.mass) { 
                ref1 = a;
                ref2 = b;
            } else {
                ref1 = b;
                ref2 = a;
            }*/
            var x = ref1.x - ref2.x;
            var y = ref1.y - ref2.y;
            var d = Math.hypot(x, y);
            var r = toRadius(a.mass) + toRadius(b.mass);
            var moveCheck = !(Math.abs(a.move.x) > 2 || Math.abs(a.move.y) > 2 || Math.abs(b.move.x) > 2 || Math.abs(b.move.y) > 2);
            if (d < r && moveCheck && (!canCombine(a) || !canCombine(b))) {
                x /= d;
                y /= d;
                ref2.x += (ref1.x - x * r - ref2.x) * 0.2;
                ref2.y += (ref1.y - y * r - ref2.y) * 0.2;
            }
        });
    });
};
```

i tried taking massive blobs as frame-of-reference and it did work. but i dont think thats how the original game works. anyways i just dont want to change the speeds of the blobs.

EDIT: Move function and speed

```
function getSpeed(n) {
    return 16 * 1.6 / Math.pow(toRadius(n), 0.32);
};

function mouseMovePlayer() {
    blobsPlayer.forEach(function(blob) {
        var angle = getMouseAngle(blob.x, blob.y);
        var speed = getSpeed(blob.mass);
        var x = mouseX - width / 2 + (cameraX - blob.x) * zoom;
        var y = mouseY - height / 2 + (cameraY - blob.y) * zoom;
        // blob.x += Math.cos(angle) * speed * Math.min(1, Math.pow(x/toRadius(blob.mass), 2));
        // blob.y += Math.sin(angle) * speed * Math.min(1, Math.pow(y/toRadius(blob.mass), 2));
        blob.x += Math.cos(angle) * speed;
        blob.y += Math.sin(angle) * speed;
    });
};
```

full codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZxeaYQ

Comment: Show the code that manages your objects' speeds. I don't see any reference to speed/velocity in the code above.

Comment: i wasnt telling that the function was changing the speed property of the objects. i was telling the function made them move faster than usual.

Comment: Yes, but my point is that "speed" is a function of distance and time. Your code above manipulates distance, so depending on how your code renders objects, they may appear to move faster because of the way speed is handled in your render code.

Comment: should i post my entire code so that u can even test it?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not understanding the problem you're describing